# ArcGIS Pro ModelBuilder failed to create new model

Tags: arcgis-pro, modelbuilder

I am using ArcGIS Pro 3.0 and when I am opening the ModelBuilder appear this message:

> Failed to create new model

In this way, it's impossible for me to utilize the tool.

How can I fix?

[image]

Comment: Where is your project? ArcPro will attempt to create the model in the default toolbox, may be you have folder/file permission issues?

Comment: Is it possibile that the origin of the problem is the folder path?
I think that I miss the folder of Model Builder in this path: ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcToolBox\toolboxes

Answer (score 0):

You have opened a tiff file as a model. I do not know why.
You can create a new model from the model builder section and create the necessary functions.